# Automatic migration handling in django

Tags: python, django, migration

I have been thinking about how to manage automatic migration like removing fields which are migrated from changing the branch like let say a field `x` was migration from dev branch and I have moved to master branch and there is no `x` field there I want to handle this automatically

Thoughts or suggestions of scirpt/library for this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had looked one library called django-nomad ( https://pypi.org/project/django-nomad/ )

This had same concept when changing branch it should let you check the changes made from last branch, there is custom command to check if there is change in migrations or not